# Add date dimesnsion to image mosiac in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to follow the instructions for how to enable time dimension to image mosaic in GeoServer:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

I added several times the data source but when I add the layer time dimension is not available.

I didn't find how to do this:

> To support time-series layers, GeoServer needs to be run in a web
>   container that has the timezone properly configured. To set the time
>   zone to be Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), add this switch when
>   launching the java process:
>
> -Duser.timezone=GMT If using a shapefile as the mosaic index store (see next section), another java process option is needed to enable
>   support for timestamps in shapefile stores:
>
> -Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true

This is an example of my image names:
T30SYJ_20190918T105029_10m_RGB.tif

And the code in indexer.properties:

```
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Double
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Caching=false
AbsolutePath=false
```

And the code in timeregex.properties:

```
regex=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{9}Z(\?!.\*[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{9}Z.\*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp must match the time/date part of your image names, so given:

```
T30SYJ_20190918T105029_10m_RGB.tif
```

you need to match 8 digits a T and 6 digits so

```
regex=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}
```

should work.